# Adding a controller to NopCommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am writing my own Payment method for NopCommerce (for Datacash to be precise, if somebody can point me towards a Datacash implementation of IPaymentMethod for NopCommerce that would also answer my question).

The [documentation provided by NopCommerce for doing this](http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/76/how-to-code-my-own-payment-method.aspx) is great, and that is what I am using as my reference, but I am very new to MVC, and the first step is to create a new controller.

I understand that, in regards to MVC, you have models, views and controllers. The model is to do with how the data for your website is modelled, the view is what you see (your HTML etc) and the controller is the programming logic behind what you see.

In any MVC Hello World Application I have done so far, you usually have a folder for your models, one for your views and one for your controllers, as shown below:

[image: MVC]

However, NopCommerce looks like this:

[image: NopCommerce]

So my question is in which folder do I put the controller I am about to create (or does it even matter)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to but it is best/wise to. 
The convention like you said is to have a View, Model and Controller.
So create a Controller folder, and you can either put your Controller class directly in the folder or do the better thing and create a NOPCommerceController folder so it looks like:

```
Controller/NOPCommerceController/SomeController.cs
```

Nice and clean.

Answer (score 3):

One observation: it looks like you didn't download the source version of nopCommerce, which does indeed have "Controllers" folders: [image: nopCommerce Nop.Web Controller folder]
[image: nopCommerce PayPalDirect Plugin "Controllers" folder]

On the nopCommerce downloads page (http://www.nopcommerce.com/downloads.aspx), look for the version "with source code", if you're looking to do customization of any sort.

Comment: Since asking the question I have discovered this, I downloaded through WebMatrix and then clicked on `Open in Visual Studio`. I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why my solution explorer didn't look anything like the ones shown in the articles on the website, when I decided to download via the website to see if it was any different. Hopefully others will come across this in the future and save themselves some time! +1

Comment: Absolutely. I write tutorial articles for nopCommerce over at Arvixe; I've just added this to my list of article ideas for next month (November - I've already written my October articles). Looking forward to seeing your plugin in action - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should create your controllers and models inside your plugin project:

[image]